# How to solve Wordpress with LAMP when everything is installed and still doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, lamp

I'm trying to install wordpress wih LAMP but I cant't get it to work. I have followed several tutorial procedures but until now Wordpress installer does not start.

*Note: I abrv http to htp.

1.- Installed Apache2

2.- Installed PHP7.0

3.- Edited info.php
3.1.- htp://localhost Shows Apache2 page
3.2.- htp://localhost/info.php shows php config

4.- Installed MySQL
4.1.- Created database
4.2.- Created user@localhost
4.3.- Granted privileges and flushed
4.4.- Edited wp-config.php and introduced databas, user and password in the respective fields.

5.- created .htaccess file (gave the 505 error so I deleted it)

6.- Granted writing rights 'chow' to $/var/www/html/ folder

7.- htp://localhost Still shows Apache2 page

8.1.- delete index.html and htp://localhost and browser finds no page

foder for installation $/var/www/htlm/

**This are terminal output for MySQL**

```
mysql> SELECT User,Host FROM mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+
| User             | Host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| David@localhost  | %         |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+

mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
| wp_umalu           |
+--------------------+

mysql> show grants for David@localhost;
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for David@localhost                                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'David'@'localhost'                   |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `wp_umalu`.* TO 'David'@'localhost' |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**This is the content of info.php**

```
<?php
    echo '<h1 style="text-align: center;">Mmm.. Soup</h1>';
    phpinfo();
?>
```

**This is my wp-config.php file**

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'wp_umalu');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'David');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'LorenIpsum');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

I also added the following line at the bottom of info.php as sugested in a tutorial

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

At this point and state nothing in the tutorials and walkthroughs seem to solve the problem; I even tryed to use another folder: $/var/www/wordpress and $/var/www/hrml/wordpress

I believe I have Apache2 and PHP installed as the pages come up in the browser and MySQL has its db and user created. Wordpress files and folders are in $/var/www/html/... But something is not right.

**This is my Distro info:**

```
I'm using XUBUNTU on a HP Pavilion

DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

Thanks in advance;

David.

Comment: The username is 'David@localhost', it should be 'David'

Comment: What happens when you go to http://localhost/wp-admin/install.php?

Comment: Thanks for you answer Jeff, It was just that!

Answer (score 0):

Update

Since the posting of my answer I kept trying to solve the issue; so I installed **MySQL Workbench** from the Ubuntu Software Center. I started meddleing with the users and database panel and grants, as well as the server panel were I made myself sure that the server was running.

I didn't make any change o add any user, but in the program (MySQL Workbench) the are these users: 'david@localhost' and 'David' if you recall, in the MySQL console output there was just david@localhost.

After messing arround with the program I went into the browser and... Magic... Wordpress installation page just appeared!... tears to my eyes

Afterwards I went into the MySQL console in the terminal and queryed the users:

```
mysql> select user,host from mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+
| user             | host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| David@localhost  | %         |
| David            | localhost |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+
```

Notice user 'David' now appears

What happened? I don't know but **MySQL Workbench** seems to have solved the problem of the server somehow.

I hope the rest will go smooth.

PS. MySQL Workbech is a very nice program by the way, easy to use and visualy pleasing.